# Importing Data in DB Visualizer

Tags: dbvisualizer

I am new to use DB Visualizer tool. I am using `free version:12.0.8`
I am able to export data from a source table as .CSV file. But am not able to import the data from the same .CSV file to target table.

Can anyone please let me know how to proceed on this. I am not getting any lead to import the data from this Free Version.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the DbVisualizer Pro edition to import data from CSV and Excel files. Sign-up for an evaluation license in **Help->Evaluate Pro Edition**.